# Disable Apple's two-factor authentication nag

Tags: two-factor-authentication

My Mac is now nagging me to setup two-factor authentication. One factor is annoying enough, thank you. Is there any way to disable the nag? (That is, my settings app icon has a big red circle complaining that there is a setting that needs to be set). My short-term "solution" has been to remove it from the dock.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even if you don't want to set up 2FA, choose the Continue button from the top of the iCloud pane, then you can choose the "not now" option and the warning will disappear.

[image]

Comment: "Not now" link does not stop the nagging. In less than 24 hrs apple will commence nagging again.

Comment: Yeah. It takes much longer than 24 hours for me, but it always comes back!